# Corestriction of smooth map

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In Lee's *Introduction to Smooth manifold*, Example 5.28 shows that corestriction of smooth map need not to be smooth.

> Let $S\subset\Bbb R^2$ be the figure eight (immersed) submanifold, with the topology and smooth structure induced by the immersion $\beta:(-\pi,\pi)\to \Bbb R^2$, $t\mapsto (\sin 2t,\sin t)$. Define a smooth map $G:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ by
> $$G(t) = (\sin 2t,\sin t).$$
> It's easy to check that the image of $G$ lies in $S$. However, as a map from $\Bbb R$ to $S$, $G$ is not even continuous, because $\beta^{-1}\circ G$ is not continuous at $t = \pi$.

The fact that $\beta^{-1}\circ G$ is not continuous at $t =\pi$ is easy to see. But to conclude $G$ is not continuous from this, I think one thing need to be ensured is the continuity of $\beta^{-1}:S\to (-\pi,\pi)$. But once $\beta^{-1}$ is continuous, $S\cong(-\pi,\pi)$ which is not as LHS is compact whereas RHS is not. Or discontinuity of $\beta^{-1}\circ G$ implies discontinuity of $\beta\circ\beta^{-1}\circ G =G$? Why $G$ is not continuous?

Comment: Can you recall what is the topology induced by $\beta$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Actually I didn't understand what 'the topology induced by $\beta$' in the context. do you know?

Comment: I don't know. You may find it in the book I guess. Without knowing the topology, there is no way for you to show whether a map is continuous.

Comment: The topology on $S$ is not the subspace (induced) topology it inherits as a subset of the plane. So it is not compact :)